# Remove 0 values in a list of list python

Tags: python, list

I need to remove the 0 values, but I don't know how, someone can help me please?

```
coord = [[(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), 0, 0, 0, 0, (1.0, 5.0), 0, 0, (3.0, 3.0)], [(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), 0, 0, 0, 0, (1.0, 5.0), 0, 0, (3.0, 3.0)]]
```

I need that coord be:

```
coord = [[(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0), (3.0, 3.0)], [(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0), (3.0, 3.0)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
[[i for i in j if i] for j in coord]
```

Output:

```
[[(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0), (3.0, 3.0)],
 [(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0), (3.0, 3.0)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension:

```py
[[item for item in sublist if item != 0] for sublist in coord]
```

This outputs:

```py
[
 [(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0), (3.0, 3.0)],
 [(1.0, 1.0), (4.0, 2.0), (1.0, 5.0), (3.0, 3.0)]
]
```